# Responsividade no Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou iniciando com o framework Bootstrap. Minha dúvida é: Quando eu específico um valor para a propriedade width na classe container, eu perco o modo responsivo de tela? porque eu fiz esse procedimento, e meu responsivo não funcionava mais. Existe alguma coisa a se fazer diante disso? Ou o container tem que ter somente uma única largura?

Answer (score 2):

Para manter o layout responsivo utilize a propriedade `max-width: ?px;` pois o width deve ficar com o valor `100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Andrew, você subscreveu a regra daquela class... dependendo do contexto você sim pode perder a responsividade já que, se seu codigo vem depois da chamada da biblioteca, as regras que escreveu vão subescrever todas as anteriores. Recomendo usar a grid para ser seu wrap e desenvolver o modulo dentro dela, ou o inverso. Não é muito legal colocar nas suas divs, ou tags de blocos, as classes das grids e containers, isso te limita ao comportamento do framework.